# I want to shoot the bullet in the direction of the character

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I want to shoot the bullet in the direction of the main player, here in this class, the bullet goes in the player's direction:

```py
class bala(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, posX, posY, velproyectil, xmax, ymax):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.Bala = img
        self.Bala = pygame.transform.rotate(self.Bala, 90)
        self.rect = self.Bala.get_rect()
        self.speedx = velproyectil
        self.speedy = velproyectil
        self.rect.top = posY - ymax
        self.rect.left = posX - xmax

    def direccion(self, personaje, personajex, personajey):
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - personajex, self.rect.y - personajey
        dist = hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.rect.x += dx * -self.speedx
        self.rect.y += dy * -self.speedy


    def dibujar(self, superficie):
        superficie.blit(self.Bala, self.rect)
```

But when I move the player, the bullets don't continue their way and the console shows me an error:

> ```
> "File "Juego_clases (Prueba2).py", line 99, in direccion
>    dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero"
> ```

The bullets are activated when the space bar is pressed down, and I want that the bullets that were fired when the bar is pressed, go through the same way.
What I want is to shoot the bullets in the player direction and that the player could dodge them.

Here is what is happening (gif): https://1drv.ms/i/s!Amz_9onOWtRI3XfQPC4aq_LhuTnj

Comment: `dist` must equal zero.  Before doing the division, you need an if statement to ensure `dist` is not 0.

Comment: But the bullets do not keep moving. Here is a "gif" that shows what happens. (https://1drv.ms/i/s!Amz_9onOWtRI3XfQPC4aq_LhuTnj)

Comment: At some point `self.rext.x` must equal `personajex` and `self.rect.y` must equal `personajey` (assuming my guess of what `hypot(dx, dy)` does).  That would make `dist` equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If the object and the target are in the same position, the distance (`dist`) is 0. This causes the error:

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

The bullet can only be moved if the distance (`dist`) is greater than 0:

```py
class bala(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def direccion(self, personaje, personajex, personajey):
        dx, dy = personajex - self.rect.x, personajey - self.rect.y
        dist = hypot(dx, dy)
        if dist > 0:
            dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
            self.rect.x += dx * self.speedx
            self.rect.y += dy * self.speedy
```